# How to add field not mapped to table in Linq to Sql

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, linq

In Entity Framework I can apply `NotMapped` attribute to a property which I do NOT want to create a column in a database table for. How to get the same effect for auto generated classes in DBML file?
I have a `StoredProcedure` that returns some additional fields.
I called `SP` like:

```
[global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.FunctionAttribute(Name = "dbo.sp_GetSupplierArticles")]
public ISingleResult<SupplierArticle> GetSupplierArticles([global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.ParameterAttribute(DbType = "BigInt")] long mainArticleId, [global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.ParameterAttribute(DbType = "BigInt")] long? userId)
{
    IExecuteResult result = this.ExecuteMethodCall(this, ((MethodInfo)(MethodInfo.GetCurrentMethod())), mainArticleId, userId);
    return ((ISingleResult<SupplierArticle>)(result.ReturnValue));
}
```

Necessary field I added into the separated partial class. Without any additional attributes it returns default value for my and applied `[Column(IsDbGenerated = false)]` in the separated partial class:

```
public partial class SupplierArticle
{
    [Column(IsDbGenerated = false)]
    public double Extra { get; set; }
}
```

So it works until I try to get `SupplierArticle` using another query (not my stored procedure):

```
db.LoadOptions = db.GenerateDataLoadOptions(entitiesToInclude);
var query =
    from shoppingCartItem in db.ShoppingCartItems
    where shoppingCartItem.UserId == userId
    select shoppingCartItem;
return query.ToList();
```

My entity is loaded due to `LoadOptions` (passed in `entitiesToInclude` parameter).
In this query and another which try to load "poor" entity with properties that defined in .dbml file I get exception:
*Invalid column name 'Extra'* and the same message for each additional property.

What is the proper way to extend entity or how to avoid that exception?

**UPD:**
If I remove all attributes exception no longer occurs. But added properties are not initialized when `SP` returns a result.

Comment: @Gert, suggested answer is not acceptable for me. I tried that way but does not work.

Comment: @GertArnold, please approve my question. Thanks

Comment: If I understand correctly, cant you create a new `model` with the required fields?

Comment: Also, if you are trying to extend a EF generated class; it should be in the same namespace.

Comment: @TheUknown, I can create and I did it in the same namespace in partial class, so I just extended auto generated class. But properties without `Column` attribute are not mapped and always contain default value of their type even Stored Procedure returns columns with the same name. After adding `Column` attribute it works fine with `SP` but not with a normal LINQ query which also try to get values that are not exist in the table.

Comment: What if you just create a subclass from SupplierArticle and add Extra field to it. The instance you get from linq you can pass to this SupplierArticleSubclass and initialize additional fields

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest creating a complex type for that stored procedure. I would even go as far as creating complex types for all of your stored procedures as this is best practice. You can then add an extension method, or a method to your partial classes that will convert the complex type returned from the stored procedure to it's related entity, and vice versa. Another option would be to include a foreign key to your complex stored procedure type, and a navigation property pointing to the correct entity.

These are, of course, solutions to a problem that EF itself doesn't address. This is expected as EF is an ORM and is not concerned with what's not persisted.

Answer (score 0):

A SQL View could be used if you wanted to.  The View is composible and LINQ to SQL does not distinguish it from a Table. First rename the original table. Then make a View with the same name as the original table, while including the extra column with a default value. Let the Stored Procedure use the table with the new name. Of course any other SQL objects with references to the table need to be updated with the new table name.  Now both LINQ to SQL and the SP will be happy.